# frame rate customMFT

Tags: multithreading, win-universal-app, ms-media-foundation

I use a custom MFT to retrieve frames in NV12. To do so I used mediaCapture.AddEffectAsync with my C++ component register in the package Manifest.

I have a class that control the capture in C++ with the Custom MFT project and a function (loadPreview) of this class that is called with a timer in my C# code. I know it could be better, because right now it is working great on powerful device, but not on the older devices. I think it is because the treatment is not made in a different thread, and loadPreview has to be finished.

By the way in loadPreview, I'm just sending the frame to a stitching engine.

Instead of using a timer, I could use the fact that every time a frame is available, the MFT use setPreviewFrame of my control capture class.

How could I handle this with multithreading please?

Comment: I think what you really want is to use [custom sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626(v=vs.85).aspx), which could be set by the [StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.startpreviewtocustomsinkasync.aspx).

Comment: What's the difference with my custom MFT?